# Passing bash script 2 parameters but one is a variable length string

Tags: bash

I'm having difficulty passing a variable length string into bash script. I can echo the item from list

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 $2 $3
printf "\n"

args=("$@")

echo ${args[0]}
echo ${args[1]}
echo ${args[2]}
printf "\n"


if [ ${args[0]} = "foo test" ]; then
        echo "working"
        printf "\n"
else
        echo "not working"
        printf "\n"
fi
```

## Command

./test.bash "foo test" foo2 foo3

## Output

> foo test foo2 foo3
>
> foo test foo2 foo3
>
> ./test.bash: line 13: [: too many arguments  not working

So I can echo the list element but when I try to use the list element to compare against a string it seems to unpack it. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Eddie

Comment: Run your script through https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Always quote your variables.